# Dissecting a square into similar 1:sqrt(2) rectangles

Tags: geometry, tiling, dissection

Can you dissect a square into similar rectangles with aspect ratio 1:sqrt(2)?

I have a suspicion you can't and that a proof could be constructed whereby you make one side of the square an integer length, then prove that the other side has to be non-integral, ie some multiple of sqrt(2).

An 'almost' answer, one side out by about 0.021%. This arose when tiling with similar but distinct rectangles of square or twice a square area.
Rectangles labelled with their area.
[image: Two dissections of an almost square into ratio 1:sqrt(2) rectangles]

Comment: Not an answer, but it could be useful to think of the field extension $\mathbb Q[\sqrt2]=\{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ as a two-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vectorspace.

Comment: This seems related to a similar, rather well-known problem/theorem, and I wonder if it can be used to prove something here. "Call an $m \times n$ rectangle *proper* if either $m$ or $n$ (or both) is an integer. Show that no improper rectangle can be tiled by proper rectangles." I first saw this problem on the [xkcd forum](http://echochamber.me/viewtopic.php?t=63093) a few years ago (solutions in the link).

Comment: Although it appears that there are two orientations for the rectangles, every $1:\sqrt{2}$ aspect rectangle can be split into two $\sqrt{2}:1$ aspect rectangles (think of paper sizes A3, A4, A5 etc.), so there's effectively only one orientation. This excludes potential solutions using only integer multiples for side lengths (like those given) but I'm still not sure whether it's possible to scale the sub-rectangles by irrational factors.

Comment: Thanks @nickgard. I was originally tiling 1:sqrt(2) rectangles, and I scaled them into integer-sided rectangle so my integer-only tiler could be used. In that case I had to tile into squares using squares plus twice-squares (horizontally oriented) which were then scaled vertically into 1:sqrt(2) rectangles, and for the other case I tiled into 2nxn rectangles which also scale vertically by sqrt(2). To scale these into what ends up as a square, I start with something like 70x99, which scales into 98.9949x99. I can't do real squares, and I'm wondering if it's even possible...

Comment: Also, I could tile say a 99*140 and then scale that down horizontally, but I would simply be solving the same problem. I deduced that this is not in fact a different problem in the continuous/non-integral world, but I'm not confident of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your intuition is right; it cannot be done.

The problem is the same as asking whether a $1:\sqrt{2}$ rectangle can be dissected into squares.

(To see this, note that as pointed out in the comments, any dissection of a square into the required rectangles can be made into a dissection into rectangles of vertical orientation only by splitting horizontal rectangles into two. Such a dissection can now be squished vertically by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ so that all the rectangles are squares.)

Dehn has shown that if a rectangle is dissected into a finite number of squares, the aspect ratio between sides of the rectangle must be rational, so a $1:\sqrt{2}$ cannot be dissected into squares.

There are some historic notes on this theorem and a proof in this paper:
[Tiling a square with similar triangles](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/1994/0001/0005/MRL-1994-0001-0005-a003.pdf), which goes into a more general version of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that.. now I can give a couple of my CPU cores a rest...